# How to create temporary object in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code.

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int) {
  }
};

int a;
int main() {
  A(a);  // Line 'a
  return 0;
}
```

What I want to do on line 'a is to create a temporary `A` with constructor `A::A(int)`. I know it's going to destruct immediately. That's what I want. But it seems the compiler is doing something equivalent to `A a`, defining variable `a` as of class `A` and initialize it using constructor `A::A()`. Of course it doesn't exist, hence the compiler error.

However, if I change my code to the following.

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int) {
  }
};

void f(A) {
}

int a;
int main() {
  f(A(a));
  return 0;
}
```

It works fine now. The compiler constructs a temporary `A` and use it to call `f`.

Why is `A(a)` different in both contexts? How is it stated in the standard or for some obscure reason? How can I construct a temporary object as in the first code sample?

Comment: You still need to give it a name. Try `A temp(a);`.

Comment: Have you tried using `A{a};` in first example because it is example of most vexing parse? You may also try to use void-cast: `static_cast<void>(A(a));`

Comment: @jakber I want `temp` to destruct immediately after this statement. It's not going to happen if I give it a name.

Comment: jakber: no, then it would exist until the end of the scope. Hot Pxl wants it to destruct at the end of the statement.

Comment: Note that it works if you use a number to initialize `A`, and that there's an error for redefinition of a if you put the `int a;` inside the main.

Comment: @ArnonZilca Yes, exactly that's why I put `a` outside of `main`.

Comment: @myaut `A{a}` won't work if `A` has a constructor that takes a `initializer_list`. the second one works, but it's kinda ugly to do a static_cast. I want to know why it behaves this way

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is another instance of the "everything that can be a declaration is a declaration" rule. [stmt.ambig]/p1:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statement*s
>   and declarations: An *expression-statement* with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a *declaration* where the first *declarator*
>   starts with a `(`. In those cases the *statement* is a *declaration*.

The standard provides the following examples:

> Assuming T is a *simple-type-specifier*,
>
> ```
> T(a)->m = 7;       // expression-statement
> T(a)++;            // expression-statement
> T(a,5)<<c;         // expression-statement
> T(*d)(int);        // declaration
> T(e)[5];           // declaration
> T(f) = { 1, 2 };   // declaration
> T(*g)(double(3));  // declaration
> ```
>
> In the last example above, `g`, which is a pointer to `T`, is initialized
>   to `double(3)`. This is of course ill-formed for semantic reasons, but
>   that does not affect the syntactic analysis.

and also:

> ```
> class T {
> // ...
> public:
>     T();
>     T(int);
>     T(int, int);
> };
>
> T(a);          // declaration
> T(*b)();       // declaration
> T(c)=7;        // declaration
> T(d),e,f=3;    // declaration
> extern int h;
> T(g)(h,2);     // declaration
> ```

The simplest way to disambiguate is probably an extra set of parentheses. `(A(a));` is unambiguously an *expression-statement*.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it included the keywords "most vexing parse", possibly with a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: what about A { a }; ?

Answer (score 5):

I could not think of a way to create a temporary without using it in some call, like you did with the function.

Why don't you want to create a named variable instead? It's lifecycle will be exactly the same as your "temporary", given how you try to declare it.

If you really want to control the destruction of your object, you could always encapsulate it in a block: `{ A tmp(a); } // temporary A object`

---

The thing is... I don't see the point of doing that. Why would you want to create a temporary object without using it? It usually means that your object creation or destruction has some side effects that you want to trigger. This is a really bad idea! You should move the side effects to a function and simply call it.

Comment: You are right that I should use a function. I was just curious why a temporary can't work. I got this idea from some RTTI code. But I guess it's a bad idea after all.

Comment: @VincentRobert I agree with you and I'm also wondering if doing something like `function( A() )` or `return A()` can affect the copy passed to or returned by the function. I mean is the object destroyed before or after the copy ? If the object is destroyed before the copy you will get an unitialized copy of the object either in the function or as return value.