# Why does clangd error with deduced_class_template_compound_type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, most-vexing-parse

The following code fails to compile

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A {
    A(T) {}
};

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    A(x); // compile failure here
}
```

and the reasons seems to be explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886000/why-cant-round-bracket-be-correctly-regarded-as-a-constructor-calling) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209962/how-to-create-temporary-object-in-c): `A(x);` is interpreted as `A x;`, a conflicting declaration of `x`.

This also explains one of clangd messages:

```
Candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
prova.cpp:8:7: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'A'
```

On the other hand, clangd also say:

```
Cannot use parentheses when declaring variable with deduced class template specialization type [deduced_class_template_compound_type]
```

What is *this* error actually referring to? I can only interpret it one way: without the parenthesis, I can provide the needed argument, e.g. `A x{3};`, but with the parenthesis I cannot declare a variable and also pass parameters to its constructor, e.g. `A(x)(3);` doesn't work, nor does `A(x){3};`.

**Why this question?**

In Chapter 11 from [*Functional Programming in C++*](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/about-this-book/), when exploring/explaining DSL, the author uses a template helper function to construct an object of a template class. The code, on the other hand, is assumed to be compiled with at least `-std=c++17` (indeed, it makes use of other C++17-specific features, like [*fold expressions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)), so in principle the class can deduce the template type if a constructor taking an argument of that template type is provided, which is the case for the example. However, removing the helper function, and renaming the class to the name of the (removed) helper function, makes the new code fail to compile at the call site, where an object is constructed with the syntax `className(objectOfOtherClass)`.

Comment: With **clang-cl** changing to `A{x};` gives: **warning : 'A' may not intend to support class template argument deduction [-Wctad-maybe-unsupported]** and **message : add a deduction guide to suppress this warning**.

Comment: @AdrianMole: That sounds like a bad warning which should be turned off.

Comment: The dupes should answer your question. If they don't, remove the first half of the question, and edit it to a more specific question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, I agree that it's "bad" in the sense that it gives me *absolutely no clue* about what's happening! I just posted it here in case anyone found it informative.

Comment: Well, they say `A(x);` is being interpreted as `A x;`, which is clearly in conflict with the earliar declaration of `x`; plus they (well, you) say that it is _not_ an example of MVP; so I guess they do answer my question.

Comment: @AdrianMole: "*it gives me absolutely no clue about what's happening*" It is telling you what is happening: `A{x}` invokes class template argument deduction, and the warning is of the opinion that this isn't something that should happen unless the type means to allow that.

Comment: But why should it be not intended, if @AdrianMole, is compiling with `-std=c++17`?

Comment: Cool. Note that MVP is not a technical term. It broadly covers syntax that might appear to humans to mean one thing, but actually means something else. See the comments on my answer in the dupe. I guess it *is* a form of a vexing parse, since it's confusing :p I wouldn't get too hung up on the phrase MVP.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Yes, I am using `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Well, since it's been vexing me for the last hour for parsing something not the way I expected, I'd say it is MVP.

Comment: Therefore @NicolBolas seems to be right in saying that the warning is bad. If not misleading!

Comment: @cigien Generally, I think the term MVP is used for cases where the parser sees/interprets something as a function declaration when the (human) author did not intend it to be so.

Comment: @AdrianMole True, but there are multiple forms of declarations that don't look like declarations, and other forms of vexing parses. But you're right, MVP *usually* refers to `T t();`

Comment: @cigien — no, `T t();` is not an example of the [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It is simply the declaration of a function named `t` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `T`. The most vexing parse arises when there is something in the parentheses. Usually the code was intended to call a function, but it instead defines an object.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, I would have thought a declaration that looks like a constructor call would qualify. Anyway, that's why I stressed not worrying about the term too much.

Comment: @cigien, thinking a bit more about it, those two dupes give part of the answer, but none of them explains what clangd is telling me. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Generally, it's preferable to notify a user that you've edited the question *after* you've edited the question.

Comment: @cigien, you're right, I'm sorry. The question is edited now.